# Troubles installing and running ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, cloud9

I am trying to use ArangoDB in my cloud9 workspace. The installation in a cloned workspace goes with no trouble, except for these lines:

```
/etc/init.d/arangodb3: 37: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)                               
/etc/init.d/arangodb3: 38: ulimit: error setting limit (Invalid argument)
that appear when starting arangodb service.
```

Then, I proceed to change the following line in `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf: endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:8529`
to this one:
    `endpoint = tcp://[workspace]-[username].c9users.io:8081`
in order to change the default running port of ArangoDB to a c9-allowed port.

That´s done with arangodb service stopped, so I the start it again, to see these lines printed out:

```
/etc/init.d/arangodb3: 37: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)                               
/etc/init.d/arangodb3: 38: ulimit: error setting limit (Invalid argument) {startup} starting up in daemon mode changed working directory for child process to '/var/tmp'
```

and then it gets my terminal back (it doesn´t keep like an ongoing process) so I type:
    `sudo service arangodb status`
which gives:
    `* arangod is not running` 
How can I get this to work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the ulimit lines are there to set the `Hard` and `Soft` quotas for open file handles, and probably exceeds your setting of `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`, so you may find resource shortages under heavy load.

Arangodb writes its logs under `/var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log` where it should inform you about reasons why it failed to start.

If you use a DNS-Name to configure your endpoint, you need to make sure that

- it resolves (`ping hostname`)
- the resolved ip is available locally (`/sbin/ifconfig`)

most probably the simplest way to fix this situation is to bind the endpoint to all available IP-Addresses using `0.0.0.0`.